# docker swarm compose constraints

Tags: docker, constraints, docker-swarm

I have one swarm manager and two swarm nodes and I would like to start a container based on some labels I defined on the docker deamon. This is the command I tried out:

```
docker -H :2376 run -e constraint:node==docker2 image/restservice
docker: Error response from daemon: Unable to find a node that satisfies the following conditions 
[available container slots]
[node==docker2].
```

here is what I get if I run docker info with swarm.

```
Containers: 13
 Running: 4
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 9
Images: 54
Server Version: swarm/1.2.3
Role: primary
Strategy: spread
Filters: health, port, containerslots, dependency, affinity, constraint
Nodes: 2
 docker-node-1: 192.168.56.104:2375
  └ ID: I32N:D2XQ:I2FL:WDDR:YQ32:BJ62:XRWJ:7TDR:XD74:IH5M:Y2W2:4PD6
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 7
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 2.061 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=, kernelversion=3.16.0-4-amd64, node=docker2, operatingsystem=Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie), storagedriver=aufs
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-08-16T18:47:05Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.11.1
 docker-node-2: 192.168.56.106:2375
  └ ID: 6VAY:KCMX:JTTG:SQXW:BFMK:MPNJ:AWEL:F3LT:FCXI:SQRO:ORDK:MOHY
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 6
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 2.061 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=, kernelversion=3.16.0-4-amd64, node=docker3, operatingsystem=Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie), storagedriver=aufs
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-08-16T18:47:19Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.11.1
Plugins: 
 Volume: 
 Network: 
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
Operating System: linux
Architecture: amd64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 4.123 GiB
Name: bdf49c666300
Docker Root Dir: 
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
```

Did I miss someting?

Comment: Are u using swam mode or swarm?
If u r using swarm - are u sure your swarm manager listens on port 2376?
Try running it on port 4000 (which is usually used by swarm and not local agents).
It looks like you try to schedule you container on a local engine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I solved the problem. No idea why it didn't work. After restarting the nodes swarm works without any problems, also docker compose works perfect with swarm.

Answer (score 0):

On the swarm mode first of all you don't run containers per se. You run services which will run containers. And your constraints are not given to service creation in the right manner. I think the best way to learn the proper way to do it is via the docker service create cli reference .
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/

Comment: Thanks for yout hint and link, it's the first project I would like to use docker in. I dont want to start containers on the swarm manager. I want to run them on the two node I connected to the swarm manager. But I don't understand why this command doesn't statisfy the constraint?

Comment: @user3756702 Either use swarm or don't. Running the containers as a service (from the manager) will result in them being scheduled on one of the nodes that make up the swarm automatically.